# Decoding Html-encoded string in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a utility function like HtmlDecode that I can use from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `html_entity_decode` as documented: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @Danish how is it not working? what do you mean by "decode", then? Which is the original format?